# How I get multi-part identifier could not be bound error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I try to perform an update on the same table depending on conditions. I know I can do the updates one by one. I tried

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
           FROM tblA a 
           INNER JOIN tblB b ON a.id = b.id 
           WHERE a.number = 1 AND a.code BETWEEN 1 AND 20)
BEGIN 
    UPDATE tblA
    SET name = b.name, zipCode = 'J2J'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    UPDATE tblA
    SET city = b.city
END
```

I get the error:

> multi-part identifier b.name, b.city could not be bound.

I would like to make the code more readable. So, is there a way to do it? Need help please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to access another table in your update you have to join that table on, and alias your tables and then `UPDATE` the primary table alias.

Also you can carry out your entire update in one go using a `CASE` expression to conditionally update the required columns. Its always best to use set based operations rather than procedural within SQL Server.

```
UPDATE A SET
  [Name] = CASE WHEN A.number = 1 AND A.code BETWEEN 1 AND 20 THEN B.[Name] ELSE A.[NAME] END
  , ZipCode = CASE WHEN A.number = 1 AND A.code BETWEEN 1 AND 20 THEN 'J2J' ELSE A.ZipCode END
  , City = CASE WHEN A.number = 1 AND A.code BETWEEN 1 AND 20 THEN A.City ELSE B.City END
FROM tblA AS A
INNER JOIN tblB AS B ON A.id = B.id;
```

Although as this repeats the same `CASE` logic 3 times I would be inclined to calculate it once in a `CROSS APPLY` e.g.

```
UPDATE A SET
  [Name] = CASE WHEN X.ConditionMet = 1 THEN B.[Name] ELSE A.[NAME] END
  , ZipCode = CASE WHEN X.ConditionMet = 1 THEN 'J2J' ELSE A.ZipCode END
  , City = CASE WHEN X.ConditionMet = 1 THEN A.City ELSE B.City END
FROM tblA AS A
INNER JOIN tblB AS B ON A.id = B.id
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (CASE WHEN A.number = 1 AND A.code BETWEEN 1 AND 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS X (ConditionMet);
```

I highly recommend reading the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) as there are many clear examples there.